# Не могу получить записи из БД при частых запросах

Tags: angularjs, http, post

Делаю приложение на angularjs, попутно изучая фреймворк. Суть: в приложении на 8 страницах происходит кроссдоменный запрос к серверу в таком виде `$http.post('http://mysite/get_users.php?name='+$scope.name+'&nick='+$scope.nick).success(function(data){$scope.users=data;});`
проблема в том что при быстром переходе между страницами в какой то момент с сервера перестают приходить записи, хотя минуту назад я заходил на эту страницу и видел множество записей из БД (смотрю в браузере в панели отладки на вкладку Networks и вижу ответ сервера "[]"). Кто может разъяснить в чём проблема? Всё дело в ангуляре или в сервере?

Comment: почти всё верно - дело в клиенте или в сервере :-) angular точно не при чем. А что поотлаживать не хотите? поставьте логирование - какие запросы с клиента уходят, скорее всего в этом и дело ... А может на сервере что не так, хто ж знает что там понаписано

Comment: с клиента всё уходит одинаково и при успешном получении данных и при получении "[]". значит всё таки сервер...

Comment: а откуда вы это знаете? по вашему коду судя логировать вы это никак не могли

Comment: Не используйте deprecated интерфейс `$http` методов. Вместо `.success(data => {})` используйте `.then(response => {response.data})`

Comment: @EugeneBartosh автор вопроса написал откуда он это знает

Comment: @AlMr смотрите. Вот вы определили, что сервер возвращает ерунду. Почему вы продолжаете отлаживать клиент? При чем тут вообще angularjs, если проблема на сервере?!

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov да сорри не обратил внимание

Comment: @AlMr убирайте нафиг метку angularjs, ставьте метку php и приводите минимальный кусок серверного кода, который отражает проблему.

Comment: но я бы на месте автора перед тем как начинать отлаживать контроллер еще раз скрупулезно проанализировал что уходит с клиента - динамический URL и данные  POST